# how do I access date column when parse_dates=True in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

When I enable parse_dates, it looks like column 0 is removed, that is, data.column.values start from 1, and not 0. How do I access the date column?

```
mytext = StringIO(unicode(mytext))

data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(mytext,
                             parse_dates=True,
                             index_col=0,
                             header=None)
```

Comment: pass `index_col=None` so it doesn't parse it as the index col, if you remove the param this is the default behaviour, also stop using `from_csv` and use `pd.read_csv` as `from_csv` is no longer maintained, all new features are going into [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index_col=0` means that column 0 is used as the index.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Index.html

```
data.index
```

returns the first column from the original csv file.

If you prefer this to be a column,

```
data.reset_index()
```

returns a new DataFrame with the old index as a column.

`index_col=False` may also be passed to `pd.read_csv()` but this will chop off the last column of data if there are not enough column names.

Comment: can I keep it as a column? I dont know how to avoid that